# How should I continue with solving first order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to analytically solve this differential equation:

$$\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=y(t)
$$

with the subject of $$y(0)=0.1$$

This is how I was computing it so far:

$$dx(t)=dty(t)$$
$$\int_{}^{}dx(t)=\int_{}^{}dty(t)$$
$$x(t)=ty(t)+C$$

This is the point where I'm unsure about how should I continue. Should I assign y(0) for C right now? Should I do anything else at this point? Also how do I know what should be assigned to t?

Comment: What is known, what is unknown ? [Note that your integration is wrong.]

Comment: Unknown is x(t).

Comment: Then $y(0)=0.1$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Why is that? What should be the result then?

Comment: See Mohammad's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is just finding anti-derivative of $y(t)$

You have misplaced the $dt$ $$\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=y(t)$$

$$dx(t)=y(t)dt$$
$$x(t)=\int y(t)dt +C$$ We need the initial value of $x(t_0)$ in order to find $C$

To be more specific
$$x(t)=x(t_0)+\int _{t_0}^t y(s)ds$$

Comment: If the unknown is $y$, then the solution is $y(t)=\dfrac{dx(t)}{dt}$, provided that $\left.\dfrac{dx(t)}{dt}\right|_{t=0}=0.1$.

Comment: Unknown is x(t)

Comment: Ah ok, the initial value x(0) is set to PI/4